# Android App only working One time, then crashes

Tags: android, camera, runtime, forceclose

Okay so I am having a problem getting my app to work.  Basically I have an game that needs to get a few pictures and Strings from the user.  I have an opening screen (OpeningScreen) that acts as a splash screen that opens up the menu (MenuScreen).  From there the user can pick to go to the game or go to the activity that shows the current pictures (PickScreen).  The user can go to that activity and from there open up another activity that gives a larger version of the picture they currently have picked or a default picture (PicOne).  Here the user has the option to take a new picture and change the current Strings.  For the most part all of it works great.  My problem occurs when:

After the user picks a picture and backs out of the app.  The next time they open it, it will force close either when I go back to PickScreen or after I press done after taking a new picture and sometimes when I go to PicOne activity.  It does not do the same thing everytime, it just crashes at one of those points.

The other issue happens when I change the 3 String names.  After pressing save and going back to PickScreen, the app crashes when going back to PicOne or if I back out of the app crashes when going from MenuScreen to PickScreen.

I know this is a lot of code to look at, but I have spent a lot of time looking around and getting code from different places for this app and I am at a point that I cannot figure out.  I figure there are many people with more knowledge than me out there, so I am asking for your help.  I know that you cannot just ask a question without showing you have been doing any work, so here it is.

Why does may app work perfectly once and then crash in various spots the second time in?  By the way it does work fine after the force close, again only once.  And why does it force close when I change the Strings?

Thanks everyone!!

The PicOne Class

```
public class PicOne extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
ImageView iv;
EditText c1, c2, c3;
Button cam, save;
Bitmap bit, bmp,other;
Intent i;
Uri uriSavedImage;
String imageFilePath10 = "", name1="", name2="", name3="";
final static int cameraData = 0; 
boolean CAMERA;
int camORgal10 = 0;
SharedPreferences gameData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.picone);
        CAMERA = false;
        iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picIV);
        cam = (Button)findViewById(R.id.camButton);
        save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.savebut);
        e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Enter1);
        e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Enter2);
        e3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Enter3);

        cam.setOnClickListener(this);
        save.setOnClickListener(this);
}
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        //camera
        case R.id.camButton:
            camORgal10 = 1;
            i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);               
            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MySpot"); 
            imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <---- 
            String fileName = "image_1.PNG"; 
            File output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);             
            uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(output);         
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
            break;

        case R.id.savebut:
            CAMERA = true;
            name1 = e1.getText().toString();
            name2 = e2.getText().toString();
            name3 = e3.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = gameData.edit();
            editor.putInt("NUM10CAMGAL", camORgal10);
            editor.putString("NUM10NAME1", name1);
            editor.putString("NUM10NAME2", name2);
            editor.putString("NUM10NAME3", name3);
            editor.commit();
            Intent goPT = new Intent(this, PickScreen.class);
            goPT.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            goPT.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            finish();
            startActivity(goPT);                
            break;

        }
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            CAMERA = true;
            name1 = e1.getText().toString();
            name2 = e2.getText().toString();
            name3 = e3.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = gameData.edit();
            editor.putInt("NUM10CAMGAL", camORgal10);
            editor.putString("NUM10NAME1", name1);
            editor.putString("NUM10NAME2", name2);
            editor.putString("NUM10NAME3", name3);
            editor.commit();
            Intent goPT = new Intent(this, PickScreen.class);
            goPT.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            goPT.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            finish();
            startActivity(goPT);

            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }   

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == cameraData)     
        {         
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data.hasExtra("data"))         
            {             
                    bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp); 



            }         
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)        
            {            
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
            }      
        }


      }



    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if(OpeningScreen.isEXIT)
        {
            finish();
        }
        gameData = getSharedPreferences(MenuScreen.MYFOLDER, 0);
        name1 = slotData.getString("NUM10NAME1", "one");
        name2 = slotData.getString("NUM10NAME2", "two");
        name3 = slotData.getString("NUM10NAME3", "three");
        e1.setText(name1);
        e2.setText(name2);
        e3.setText(name3);
        camORgal10 = gameData.getInt("NUM10CAMGAL", 0);
        if(camORgal10 == 0)
        {
            bit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red);
        }
        else if(camORgal10 == 1)
        {
            File imgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MySpot/image_1.PNG");
            if(imgFile.exists())
            {
               bit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());   
            }
            else
            {
                bit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            bit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red);
        }           
        iv.setImageBitmap(bit);
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

OpeningScreen

```
public class OpeningScreen extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 public static boolean isEXIT = false;

@Override   
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    isEXIT = false;
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(2500);
            } catch(InterruptedException e){

            } finally{
                Intent toMenu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuScreen.class);
                toMenu.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                //toMenu.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                finish();
                startActivity(toMenu);                  
            }               
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    finish();
    super.onPause();        
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(isEXIT)
    {
        finish();
    }

    super.onResume();
}    
}
```

MenuScreen

```
public class MenuScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
float x,y;
int camORgal = 0;
ImageButton play, edit, more;
Intent i;
public static String MYFOLDER = "GAMEDATA";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    play = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.IBplay);
    edit = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.IBedit);
    more = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.IBmore);
    play.setOnClickListener(this);
    edit.setOnClickListener(this);
    more.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        OpeningScreen.isEXIT = true;
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.IBplay:
        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TheGame.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        finish();
        startActivity(i);           
        break;
    case R.id.IBedit:
        i = new Intent(this, PickScreen.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        finish();
        startActivity(i);           
        break;
    case R.id.IBmore:

        break;
    }
}

}
```

PickScreen

```
public class PickScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button bPic1, bPic2, bPic3;
ImageView ivpic3,ivpic2, ivpic1;
TextView TVpic3a, TVpic3b, TVpic3c, TVpic2a, TVpic2b, TVpic2c, TVpic1a, TVpic1b, TVpic1c;
Intent pageMove;
SharedPreferences gameData;
int camORgal10 = 0;
String threeNamea = "", threeNameb = "", threeNamec = "", twoNamea = "", twoNameb = "", twoNamec = "", oneNamea = "", oneNameb = "", oneNamec = "";

Bitmap bmp1, bmp2,bmp3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.paytable);
                intitializeThings();        
}


public void intitializeThings()
{
    bPic1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pic1but);
    bPic2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pic2but);
    bPic3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pic3but);
    ivpic3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivpic3a);
    ivpic2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivpic2a);
    ivpic1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivpic1a);
    TVpic3a = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pic3TVa);
    TVpic3b = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pic3TVb);
    TVpic3c = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pic3TVc);
    TVpic2a = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pic2TVa);
    TVpic2b = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pic2TVb);
    TVpic2c = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pic2TVc);
    TVpic1a = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pic1TVa);
    TVpic1b = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pic1TVb);
    TVpic1c = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pic1TVc);


    bPic1.setOnClickListener(this);
    bPic2.setOnClickListener(this);
    bPic3.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.pic1but:
        pageMove = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PicOne.class);
        pageMove.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        pageMove.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        //pageMove.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        finish();
        startActivity(pageMove);

        break;
    case R.id.pic2but:
        pageMove = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PicTwo.class);
        pageMove.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        //pageMove.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        startActivity(pageMove);
        finish();
                          break;
    case R.id.pic3but:
        pageMove = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PicThree.class);
        pageMove.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        //pageMove.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        startActivity(pageMove);
        finish();   
                          break;            
    }
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        Intent goOP = new Intent(this, MenuScreen.class);
        goOP.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        goOP.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        finish();
        startActivity(goOP);

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();   


        gameData = getSharedPreferences(MenuScreen.MYFOLDER, 0);
        oneNamea = gameData.getString("NUM10NAME1", "one");
        oneNameb = gameData.getString("NUM10NAME2", "two");
        oneNamec = gameData.getString("NUM10NAME3", "three");
        camORgal10 = gameData.getInt("NUM10CAMGAL", 0);


        if(camORgal10 == 1)
        {
            File pic1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MySpot/image_1.PNG");
            if(pic1.exists())
            {
                bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pic1.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            else
            {
                bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red);
            }
        }

        else if(camORgal10 == 0)
        {
            bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red);
        }
        else
        {
            bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red);
        }


        File pic2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MySpot/image_2.PNG");
        File pic3 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MySpot/image_3.PNG");


        if(pic2.exists())
        {
            bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pic2.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        else
        {
            bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.purple);
        }
        if(pic3.exists())
        {
            bmp3 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pic3.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        else
        {
            bmp3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.green);
        }


        ivpic3.setImageBitmap(bmp3);

        ivpic2.setImageBitmap(bmp2);

        ivpic1.setImageBitmap(bmp1);

        TVpic1a.setText(oneNamea);
        TVpic1b.setText(oneNameb);
        TVpic1c.setText(oneNamec);

}


}
```

Comment: what is logcat telling you about the crash?

Comment: I can't use it on an emulator because of the camera, so it is on my phone.  I do not know how to get to log cat on that.

Comment: You can use logcat with a device, just need to say "adb logcat -s devid" where devid can be found using "adb devices"

Answer (score 1):

Logcat will give you a stack trace, and then use debug to pinpoint the place where it's crashing. Debugging a modern application by reading through code, especially OOP code, is nearly impossible.

Answer (score 0):

This was probably caused by the fact the AOS does not closes apps really but you might think is does. So on the next start AOS doesn't start your app "from the scratch" but it raises your undead cached app. And since your logic wasn't expected that your app crashes. I'm pretty sure it starts OK once again right after the crash but the next start once again crashes -> the loop. So to avoid that use System.exit(0) (most advanced devs gonna say its a bad practice) to ensure your app wont became a zombie OR change the logic of your app so it wont crash on the next start cuz the main activity is still there.